# How to run mongodb again after executing db.shutdownServer(); in the admin db

Tags: linux, mongodb, shell, fedora

I was just learning mongodb. I command I entered are :

use admin
db.shutdownServer();

This shutdown the database. After that whenever I'm writing mongo to start mongoDB it gives me :

> MongoDB shell version: 3.0.12 connecting to: test
>   2016-10-09T18:24:27.661+0530 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to
>   127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused 2016-10-09T18:24:27.664+0530 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to
>   server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
>       at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
>       at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179 exception: connect failed

When I run this : sudo service mongodb start

I get :

> Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  mongodb.service Failed to start
>   mongodb.service: Unit mongodb.service failed to load: No such file or
>   directory.

I tried other different commands (even I've re installed it again) but none of them restarted mongodb.

How to start mongodb?

Comment: Are you sure you are running MongoDB as service?

Comment: @Saleem yes ...

Answer (score 1):

shut down the node

> ```
> :SECONDARY> db.shutdownServer()
> ```

up

> ```
> :~$ mongod --config /db/mongod-repl-2.conf
> :SECONDARY> rs.slaveOk()
> :SECONDARY> show dbs
> admin         0.000GB
> config        0.000GB
> local         0.000GB
> testDatabase  0.000GB
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fork your service again,
Try

```
mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongo/ --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```